# Information loss problem if almost perfect black body

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, condensed-matter, quantum-information, thermal-radiation

Assume a almost perfect black body at temperature zero and consider pointing a signal, let's say a laser beam (pure state), on this body. What happens with the information of the beam?

My thoughts go like this: The described body will absorb and scatter the beam and will heat up. Now the scatter part is still pure but when the body radiates the absorbed beam we only have thermal black body radiation which doesn't give us any information about the initial beam. Apparently we are losing information.
I am now thinking about how this problem could be solved. This problem is very similar to the Gedankenexperiment by Bekenstein and Wheeler and lead to the generalized second law of thermodynamics [(Bekenstein’s generalized second law of thermodynamics)](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0370269315008114?token=2174F6353C7332B053E25D59F09C645A664C4EF04F0B6A626A647520A1A5E4B0B96CB0C8EE9CF1F48FBAA8AE424152F6). I am wondering if there is an explanation in non black hole physics for these kinds problem as well.